# send multiple files parallely using tcp connection between client and server in c#

Tags: c#, tcp, parallel-processing, sendfile

**How can i send multiple files between a client and a server in c# parallely. I have already  tried to send single file ,the code is given below.**

And also please explain difference between sending a file without using socket(as done below) and using socket to send a file

**SERVER SIDE**

```
TcpListener filelistener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(GetIP()), 8085);
            MessageBox.Show("server started");
             filelistener.Start();
            TcpClient client = filelistener.AcceptTcpClient();
            Message("Client connection accepted from :" + client.Client.RemoteEndPoint + ".");

             byte[] buffer = new byte[1500];
            int bytesread = 1;


            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\ab\\Desktop\\abc.txt");

            while (bytesread > 0)
            {
                bytesread = client.GetStream().Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                if (bytesread == 0)
                    break;
                writer.BaseStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                Message(bytesread + " Received. ");
                  }
                writer.Close();
```

**CLIENT SIDE**

```
 try
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(textBox1.Text);
            TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
            tcpClient.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(GetIP()), 8085));


            byte[] buffer = new byte[1500];
            long bytesSent = 0;

            while (bytesSent < sr.BaseStream.Length)
            {
                int bytesRead = sr.BaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, 1500);
                tcpClient.GetStream().Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                Message(bytesRead + " bytes sent.");

                bytesSent += bytesRead;
            }

            tcpClient.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("finished");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TCPClient and TCPListener that both use sockets internally and simply provide a higher level of abstraction. In other words, you are still using sockets, just not directly.

In order to send multiple files in parallel, you will need the server to be able to accept more than one connection. There are several ways you can accomplish this but the general idea is the same:

- start your listener
- as soon as any client connects, don't block while you are handling that client, but instead attempt to connect the next client connection as soon as it is available
- for each connected client, handle the connection to receive the file data and do whatever you need to do with it

see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.accepttcpclientasync(v=vs.110).aspx

On the client, you can spin up a number of TCPClient objects, one for each file you'd like to send and send the data to your listener.

You will have to figure out the logistics (the *protocol*) of your data transfers. As you get the incoming data transfer for each file you are receiving on the listener side, you have to decide what each file represents and who it is from. The details here are quite subjective and not really a good fit for StackOverflow Q&A.